# How to disable or override an app from launching in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

Is there someway for an app to listen in the background on ios for certain apps trying to launch and not allow them to and present the background app instead?

Also be aware this is not for adware, a virus or anything malicious.It is for limiting the usage of certain apps specified by the user.

Comment: Hijacking an app that the user attempted to launch and launch your app instead? No, you can't do that, that's basically a virus.

Comment: Lol. It does sound like that but it's for a productivity app and would only be for a limited amount of time and can also be disabled..

Comment: With that said can you help EmilioPelaez?

Comment: As a general rule, Apple will never let you do anything that changes the behavior of the system. When your app is in the background it can only be re-activated by the user, and it can't interfere with other apps or the functionality of the system.

Comment: What's wrong with using the [parental controls](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201304) or the  [Screen Time](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2018/06/ios-12-introduces-new-features-to-reduce-interruptions-and-manage-screen-time/) "App Limits" function for this purpose?